# Why are FAQ posts community wiki?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki, meta-faq

I've recently [started up a community FAQ over at Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1280/3808), basically copy/pasting the SO one. It contained this excerpt:

> Flag for a moderator to mark **community wiki**.  Any FAQ post not yet community wiki should be made into a community wiki.

That post got these comments:

> Why CW-ify? I don't see that FAQs need to be easy to edit.

and

> I've added the faq tag. I agree with Peter that it doesn't need to be easy to edit. ;-)

That makes sense, so why *are* FAQ posts CW?

Comment: Typically it was because should you really receive reputation for something that ends up being a product of the community and not you?

Comment: @George Ah, good point, but with the impending MSO/MSE split that soon won't be an issue anymore.

Comment: @George however in that case it will become community wiki naturally from many edits. If you write it perfectly the first time it seems like a seperate issue. However; an FAQ does get additional attention

Comment: FAQ question should always have one single, canonical, answer. That answer is then maintained by ordinary users who keep editing it to make it correct and up to date. So @George comment holds true, in ideal FAQ entry it's product of the community and not a single user. I'm not familiar enough with per-site metas, but MSE will inherit most, if not all, the FAQs from here so it's still very much relevant.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let's first look at what Community Wiki posts do:

- Greatly lower the reputation requirement for editing the post
- Prevent the post from yielding reputation from votes
- Reduce the profile of the attribution

#### Edit reputation requirement

A big issue with the reputation requirement on meta (the exception being MSE), where these [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) posts are hosted, is that *there are no suggested edits*. An edit can only be done by higher-reputation users.
[faq](/questions/tagged/faq) posts are generally about *one* subject at a time, with *one* all-encompassing answer to that subject. This means that, whenever something changes about the state of affairs regarding that [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) post, it should be easy to amend and update, rather than requiring someone with high-reputation to edit it. There is, essentially, no way (except for a flag) to inform these high-reputation users of the necessary edit.

<del>That said, by the nature of the SE system, such a post would become a Community Wiki organically - after a given amount of edits it is automatically converted.</del>

#### Post reputation yield

That's a tricky one. See, non-MSE metas don't actually *have* reputation, so this seems irrelevant, doesn't it? Well, kinda. The reputation (or, rather, the computed votes) still exist, contribute to tag score and various badges.
The fundamental problem of *actual* reputation yield, however, is relevant only to MSE, so this can - largely - be ignored for non-MSE metas.

#### Attribution

There's a big difference between how a Community Wiki post is attributed and how a regular post is attributed. A Community Wiki post is *much* more subtle, and points out rather clearly that the post is a *community* effort, rather than the work of a single user. [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) posts are not supposed to be the work of one user, but a *community* aid, decision or other important notice. Attributing these (with the coverage they get) to a single user seems rather dishonest to the community at large.

#### Conclusion

In my opinion, *especially* that third point is a good reason to keep the Community Wiki status on [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) posts, even on non-MSO metas. More often than not these [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) posts aren't even original content, but instead stripped straight from MSO, so it makes sense to go with low-profile attribution.
At the end of the day, it's up to the individual site to decide, but I feel there are very good reasons to maintain this.